# How to reference pointers to the same struct object from outside the scope in which they were defined

Tags: go, object, pointers, memory, struct

In the below code, two pointer variables, `r1` and `r2` (of type `*Rect`), reference the same struct object (of type `Rect`):

```
type Rect struct {
    width int
}

func main() {
    r1 := new(Rect)
    r2 := new(Rect)
    r1 = r2

    fmt.Printf("%p, %p", r1, r2) // prints the addresses of the Rects being pointed to by each variable
}
```

`0xc00001c038, 0xc00001c038` **(GOOD OUTPUT)**

How would you reference `r1` and `r2` to the same struct object from outside of the function in which they were defined?  In other words, how would you create a function to replace `r1 = r2`?  My attempt at dereferencing and then assigning the variables from within an external function did not succeed at referencing `r1` to `r2`'s referenced struct object:

```
func assign(r1, r2 *Rect) {
    *r1 = *r2
}

func main() {
    r1 := new(Rect)
    r2 := new(Rect)
    assign(r1, r2)

    fmt.Printf("%p, %p", r1, r2) // prints the addresses of the Rects being pointed to by each variable
}
```

`0xc00001c030, 0xc00001c038` **(BAD OUTPUT)**

**PLAYGROUND:** https://go.dev/play/p/ld0C5Bkmxo3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change where a pointer points to within a function, you have to pass the address of it:

```
func assign(r1, r2 **Rect) {
    *r1 = *r2
}

func main() {
    r1 := new(Rect)
    r2 := new(Rect)
    assign(&r1, &r2)

    fmt.Printf("%p, %p", r1, r2) // prints the addresses of the Rects being pointed to by each variable
}
```

**PLAYGROUND:** https://go.dev/play/p/5fAakjB50JJ

Comment: I had the impression that Go implicitly did this when you pass arguments into a *Struct parameter of a function, but I guess not.  Thank you for your response—this worked perfectly.